# Timeout of pyodbc connection - recycle conn?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, rollback

At the beginning of my process, I connect to a SQL Server database

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=" + driver + ";SERVER=" + server + ";PORT=" + port + ";DATABASE=" + dbn + ";UID=" + user +";PWD=" + pwd)
```

and then use that connection and execute queries with this code:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    if cur.description is not None:
        data = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
        return data
except Exception as err:
    conn.rollback()
    raise err
cur.close()
```

It works fine until the code does not execute a query for several hours, then I get the following error:

```
cur.execute(sql)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed (20006) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

It seems that there is a timeout. Is there any way to recycle the existing connection (conn)?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't want to examine the exception and reissue a new connection? Or possibly close the connection after each read and issue a new connection?

Comment: That would be possible. But in sqlalchemy for example there is the possibility to recycle the connection with the parameters pool_pre_ping and pool_recycle after a predefined time. I wonder if there is a more elegant way (recycle) with pyodbc than setting up a new connection when an error occurs.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.nuomiphp.com/eplan/en/36973.html) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this creates a new connection when an error occurs. But since I have a function that uses many different connection strings, this is probably not the smartest way to do it.

Comment: @TomD - Why not just use a SQLAlchemy Engine object instead of a pyodbc Connection object? After all, that's what pandas [specifies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html): "If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported."